# System.TimeZoneNotFoundException in release compilation for UWP App

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

While trying to compile my UWP App in Release Mode I get the following error `ILT0025: Inconsistent type forwarders were found for type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException'`. The App runs successfully in Debug Mode without any errors.

Problem started when I upgraded my App's minimal and target Windows version to 16299 from 15063. Downgrade is not possible as some part of my app relies on 16299 controls.

I tried adding a reference to `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v2.22.302111727` as it says in this thread https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/4768 and even checked the newest version of that package but it hasn't changed anything.

I have following packages in my App:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client">
  <Version>5.2.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory">
  <Version>3.17.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
  <Version>6.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <Version>10.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple">
  <Version>4.4.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms">
  <Version>2.4.0.38779</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem? How did you solve that?

Comment: Had this issue. I couldn't find any normal solution but creating a new project and drag'n'drop everything helped.

Comment: Does anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Same problem here, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Delete the following files from your project:

`project.lock.json
*.nuget.props
*.nuget.targets`

The question has been answered in this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/4768